# Can't find mediatomb or minidlna to install on ubuntu-server

Tags: installation, server, mediatomb, minidlna

Installed ubuntu-server 12.04LTS (64bit) but cannot install mediatomb and minidlna.
The reason is that "apt-get mediatomb install" can not find it. The same when I try it for minidlna.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [minidlna](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/minidlna), and [mediatomb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/mediatomb) are available for all Ubuntu versions from the Universe repository.

To install them issue the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update  # to update the cache
sudo apt-get install minidlna # for minidlna
sudo apt-get install mediatomb # for mediatomb
```

After installation these applications will have to be configured to meet our personal setup before we can use them.

Also see

- [Manpage for apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get)